# Trying to run quotacheck on CentOS

Tags: centos, vps, disk-space-utilization

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-5.6-x86_64-ispconfig-3) to set up my VPS and install ISPConfig with quota support.
The tutorial asks me to run:

```
touch /aquota.user /aquota.group
chmod 600 /aquota.*
mount -o remount /
quotacheck -avugm
quotaon -avug
```

However, when I run `quotacheck -avugm` it says the command quotacheck is not found:
`-bash: quotacheck: command not found`

So I had a Google, apparently quotacheck is in `/sbin/`, so I'd have to run it from `/sbin/`, so I did `/sbin/quotacheck -avugm`, still same, did an `ls -s` on /sbin, it isn't there. Had a look at the `$PATH`, `/sbin` is included.

How can I still run this?

Comment: Which tutorial?

Comment: Your solution worked, but the tutorial is: http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-5.6-x86_64-ispconfig-3

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the package that includes the quota tools.  Google suggests it is the `quota` package that you want.